# Tomcat: Configuring temp folder

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, tomcat6

I have some webservices running on tomcat that make tasks on a quite big repository.
After a few days of run I realized that the tomcat temp folder ($CATALINA_HOME/temp) contains a huge amount of files which may affect the server behavior.
Is there any way to configure the temp folder in order to delete files older then a certain amount of time or to disable the temp folder if it's not needed?

Answer (score 1):

If your files' life-times are max "10" minutes then you can use below cron job to periodically clean your temp directory.

Let's say your tomcat's temp directory is `"/usr/server/tomcat7/temp"`:

**Cron job notation:**

```
0 1 * * * find /usr/server/tomcat7/temp -type f -mmin +10 -delete
```

**Code description:**

- `0 1 * * *` --> everyday at 1am
- `find /usr/server/tomcat7/temp` --> find files in directory "/usr/server/tomcat7/temp"
- `-type f` --> only the items whiches' types are "file"
- `-mmin +10` --> only the ones older than "10" minutes
- `-delete` --> delete them

---

For the ones who are new to Cron:

**How to set the Cron job (Centos version):**

- If not installed, install with `sudo yum install cron`
- Open cron configuration file with `crontab -e` (this will open the config file with [vim](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_06_02.html))
- Press a letter to activate vim's "type" mode
- Paste the "Cron job notation" given above
- To save and exit, first press "esc" and then type "`:x`" and press enter
- You must see "`installing new crontab`" on the command line

Now you are completely ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think disabling the temp dir makes no sense as it is obvoiusly a requirement for the deployed app. File upload is usually implemented using temp files for example.

If I were you I would write a simple shell script for the cleanup and put it into the crontab for example.